# How to implement conditional 'go back' button in nextjs 13

Tags: next.js13, nextjs-app-beta

I have a webview app that has a header component on each page, the header should render `<-` (go back button) if user is not on the home page and have the name of that page

if I add this `header` component in the `layout.ts` how do I change the "name" for each page?

also for some of nested pages I need to manually specify where to go back(for example on `step 3` "go back" should navigate to `step 1`)